# How many simultaneous threads can be used to load test a web application?

Tags: java, tomcat, junit, jmeter

I need to find my web application's performance and load test it. The application currently has a Tomcat configuration of 25 threads maximum and there are two such servers.

Does it mean that I should do load testing for 50 concurrent requests?
And what happens where there are more requests; does it go to the thread waiting queue in Tomcat?
In case it goes for a thread wait queue, can I test the application with more than 50 requests?

Comment: No. You should load test with the number of concurrent requests you want your application to support, check if your performance requirements are met, measure and adjust the number of threads (and other parameters) in order to better meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat can work in 2 modes:

- BIO (blocking IO) where 1 thread can serve maximum 1 connection
- NIO (non-blocking IO) where 1 thread can serve many more connections

Most probably your application is using the latter one, check out [Understanding the Tomcat NIO Connector and How to Configure It](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-tomcat-nio) guide for the overview. On the other hand even in case of using the BIO connector application might still be able to operate fast enough to serve more than 50 users.

In both cases, you should treat your backend as a "black box" (imagine you don't know anything about the configuration) and focus on testing non-functional requirements.

The essential performance testing types you should be considering are:

- **Load Testing**: check how does your system behave when the **anticipated** amount of concurrent users are using it.
- **Soak Testing**: the same, but assuming longer test duration, i.e. overnight or weekend. This way you will be able to see if there are any [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), how does log rotation work, whether application cleans after itself so it won't run out of disk space, etc.
- **Stress Testing**: the process of identifying the boundaries of your application, i.e. start with 1 virtual user and increase the load until application response time will be within reasonable boundaries or errors start occurring.

See [Why ‘Normal’ Load Testing Isn’t Enough](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-%E2%80%98normal%E2%80%99-load-testing-isn%E2%80%99t-enough) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri 

Does it mean that during stress testing we can test it with more than maximum threads.

Comment: The idea of stress test is determining the maximum amount of connected users, in case of Tomcat with NIO connector it may be many more than defined threads